# How to represent conflicts with a proper container?

Tags: c++, containers

I have a number of shapes (typed Shape). Two shapes conflict each other if they have overlapping area. I'd like to use a proper container to record all the conflicts among those shapes. The first one I try is std::set of a pair like below

```
std::set<std::pair<Shape*, Shape*>> conflicts;

// Add a conflict. Putting shape1 first means shape1 has priority over shape2.
conflicts.insert(make_pair(&shape1, &shape2));

// Add another where shapes is at the second.
conflicts.insert(make_pair(&shape3, &shape1));
```

However, it is not easy to get all conflicts related to a shape, like shape1 because sometimes shape1 appears at the second in the conflict. Any good way to do it?

Comment: How about using your own class instead of a pair? A custom equality operator could make [A, B] == [B, A]. You'd also have to implement a less than operator that is consistent with this.

Comment: These are _collisions_, not "conflicts".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two choices:

1. Insert each conflict between two shapes `a` and `b` twice into a [`std::multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap) or [`std::unordered_multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap) So `(a,b)` and `(b,a)`. (set is dual to map) (you need a multimap so you can store more than one conflict for each shape)

   Maintaining a list/set in the shape itself or using a map from shape to list/set is just the same in green.
2. Use something like [boost::multi_index_container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

   I expect this solution to be less efficient and comfortable actually.

Comment: Just a clarification wouldn't a `multimap` enable the insertion the same values several times (e.g something like `mymm.insert ({shape1,shape2});... mymm.insert ({shape1,shape2});`)? and then `mymm` will contain `shape2` twice for `shape1`

Comment: Yes, but the important part, why I said use a multimap, is that for every shape, there can be multiple conflicting other shapes.

Comment: I think [this](http://ideone.com/2vdGYm) issue is not that bad (although can introduce subtle bugs if the OP decides to count collisions imagine that more then X collisions will mean something ) but it does feel a little weird in the sense that _a shape can collide more then once with the same shape_ I don't know maybe I'm the odd one :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on Boost.MultiIndex:

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_container_iterator.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct shape{};
struct collision{shape *sh1,*sh2;};

using collision_track=multi_index_container<
  collision,
  indexed_by<
    hashed_non_unique<member<collision,shape*,&collision::sh1>>,
    hashed_non_unique<member<collision,shape*,&collision::sh2>>
  >
>;

using shape_ptr_iterator=boost::shared_container_iterator<std::vector<shape*>>;

inline std::pair<shape_ptr_iterator,shape_ptr_iterator>
collisions(shape* sh,const collision_track& ct)
{
  boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<shape*>> res(new std::vector<shape*>());
  for(auto p=ct.get<0>().equal_range(sh);p.first!=p.second;p.first++)res->push_back(p.first->sh2);
  for(auto p=ct.get<1>().equal_range(sh);p.first!=p.second;p.first++)res->push_back(p.first->sh1);
  return std::make_pair(
    shape_ptr_iterator(res->begin(),res),
    shape_ptr_iterator(res->end(),res));
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  shape sh1,sh2,sh3;
  std::cout<<&sh1<<","<<&sh2<<","<<&sh3<<"\n";

  collision_track ct={{&sh1,&sh2},{&sh2,&sh3},{&sh3,&sh1}};
  for(auto p=collisions(&sh1,ct);p.first!=p.second;p.first++)std::cout<<*p.first<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) where each of the shapes is a key and the value is the list (which could be actually a [`set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) if quick searching is needed e.g answer "does shape X collide with shape Y by checking `conflicts[X].count(Y)`) of shapes it collides with.

A small [demo](http://ideone.com/pf1PWW):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct shape {

    int x;
};

int main() {
    cout.setf(std::ios::boolalpha);
    shape arr[6] = {{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}}; // some shapes
    map<shape*,set<shape*> > c; // although would consider smart pointers
    c[&arr[0]].insert(&arr[1]);
    c[&arr[1]].insert(&arr[0]);

    cout << "Shape 1 collides with 0: " <<  c[&arr[1]].count(&arr[0]) <<endl;
    cout << "Shape 1 collides with 2: " <<  c[&arr[1]].count(&arr[2]) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```